# Appium client can’t connect to Appium server locally

Tags: macos, appium

I’m using mac, version 10.14.6, Appium v 1.15 and Java 8.

I launch Appium as application and then trying to launch my autotests, but there is a fail when Java tries to create instance of AndroidDriver

```
driver = new AndroidDriver(url, desiredCapabilities);
```

look at the screenshot with capabilities

[image]

The stacktrace

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
Build info: version: ‘3.141.59’, revision: ‘e82be7d358’, time: ‘2018-11-14T08:17:03’
System info: host: ‘build-mac’, ip: ‘fe80:0:0:0:182d:c3ec:3e3:65fd%en0’, os.name: ‘Mac OS X’,         os.arch: ‘x86_64’, os.version: ‘10.14.6’, java.version: ‘1.8.0_231’
Driver info: driver.version: SelenideDriver
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.lambda$5(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:251)
at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:250)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:323)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:37)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:86)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:96)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:94)
at com.whimstay.automation.core.drivers.DriverManager.createDriver(DriverManager.java:45)
```

I guess it’s probably due to Mac security policy, because on Windows everything is okay.
What should I do to fix the issue?

Comment: Please add the appium logs also

Comment: I don't see any logs in UI of Appium

Answer (score 0):

Had to specify the URL like this `http://localhost:4723`